# How to randomly change the picture of several picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I basically want to know how I can optimize this code. I was trying to create somehow a program that could change the photo of a picturebox, but with a randomizer. Basically, each photo would have its percentage of chance to appear in the picturebox, and after several attempts, the only thing that worked for me was this ugly and badly optimized code, but if I try to fix it, the program simply fails. Well, my code generates a random number from 1 to 100 and depending on the number that is generated, one of the six photos is chosen. It is working, however it changes the image from just one picturebox, and I have over 50 that I want to switch (still random). I put it to change everything in a single button, it took me an hour to do this, and I saw that the program gets very slow so it's out of the question. Is there any way to change them all at once using only one code, but keeping random all 50 pictureboxes?

The idea is that at the end of the 50 picturebox are randomly filled with photos, with pictures that can be repeated, but some are less likely to appear than others.

I know, it was a bit confusing, but even if someone can help me, thank you right away.

My code:

```
randomvalue = random.Next(1, 101)
    If randomvalue = "1" Or randomvalue = "2" Or randomvalue = "3" Or randomvalue = "4" Or randomvalue = "5" Or randomvalue = "6" Or randomvalue = "7" Or randomvalue = "8" Or randomvalue = "9" Or randomvalue = "10" Or randomvalue = "11" Or randomvalue = "12" Or randomvalue = "13" Or randomvalue = "14" Or randomvalue = "15" Or randomvalue = "16" Or randomvalue = "17" Or randomvalue = "18" Or randomvalue = "19" Or randomvalue = "20" Or randomvalue = "21" Or randomvalue = "22" Or randomvalue = "23" Or randomvalue = "24" Or randomvalue = "25" Or randomvalue = "26" Or randomvalue = "27" Or randomvalue = "28" Or randomvalue = "29" Or randomvalue = "30" Or randomvalue = "31" Then
        btnOre1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\AppData\Local\imgsx\img1.png")
    End If

    If randomvalue = "32" Or randomvalue = "33" Or randomvalue = "34" Or randomvalue = "35" Or randomvalue = "37" Or randomvalue = "38" Or randomvalue = "39" Or randomvalue = "40" Or randomvalue = "41" Or randomvalue = "42" Or randomvalue = "43" Or randomvalue = "44" Or randomvalue = "45" Or randomvalue = "46" Or randomvalue = "47" Or randomvalue = "48" Or randomvalue = "49" Or randomvalue = "50" Or randomvalue = "51" Or randomvalue = "52" Or randomvalue = "53" Or randomvalue = "54" Or randomvalue = "55" Or randomvalue = "56" Or randomvalue = "57" Then
        btnOre1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\AppData\Local\imgsx\img2.png")
    End If

    If randomvalue = "58" Or randomvalue = "59" Or randomvalue = "60" Or "61" Or randomvalue = "62" Or randomvalue = "63" Or randomvalue = "64" Or randomvalue = "65" Or randomvalue = "66" Or randomvalue = "67" Or randomvalue = "68" Or randomvalue = "69" Or randomvalue = "70" Or randomvalue = "71" Or randomvalue = "72" Or randomvalue = "73" Or randomvalue = "74" Or randomvalue = "75" Or randomvalue = "76" Or randomvalue = "77" Then
        btnOre1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\AppData\Local\imgsx\img3.png")
    End If

    If randomvalue = "78" Or randomvalue = "79" Or "80" Or randomvalue = "81" Or randomvalue = "82" Or randomvalue = "83" Or randomvalue = "84" Or randomvalue = "85" Or randomvalue = "86" Or randomvalue = "87" Or randomvalue = "88" Or randomvalue = "89" Or randomvalue = "90" Then
        btnOre1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\AppData\Local\imgsx\img4.png")
    End If

    If randomvalue = "91" Or randomvalue = "92" Or randomvalue = "93" Or randomvalue = "94" Or randomvalue = "95" Or randomvalue = "96" Or randomvalue = "97" Or randomvalue = "98" Or randomvalue = "99" Or randomvalue = "100" Then
        btnOre1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\AppData\Local\imgsx\img5.png")
    End If

    If randomvalue = "36" Then
        btnOre1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\AppData\Local\imgsx\img6.png")
    End If
```

Comment: First thing you should learn is that a string is not a number. random.Next returns an integer and you can use simply comparison operators in your conditions. Like > = and <= For example    _If randomvalue >= 1 Or randomvalue <= 31 then_

Comment: I tried to do like that:   

           `If randomvalue < 32 Then
btnOre1.Image [...]

          If randomvalue < 58 and > 31 Then
btnOre1.Image [...]`

But that just gave me the error: expected expression.

Comment: @Happy It should have been `If randomvalue < 58 and randomvalue > 31 Then btnOre1.Image [...]`, although I think most people would have it as `If randomvalue > 31 and randomvalue < 58 Then btnOre1.Image [...]`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the actual numbers are because I couldn't be bothered counting but lets' say that your six images should have 10%, 20%, 10%, 20%, 10% and 30% chances of being used respectively.  You can use a `Select Case` to easily filter a random number, e.g.

```
Select Case myRandom.Next(0, 100)
    Case Is < 10 '0-9
        'Use first image
    Case Is < 30 '10-29
        'Use second image
    Case Is < 40 '30-39
        'Use third image
    Case Is < 60 '40-59
        'Use fourth image
    Case Is < 70 '60-69
        'Use fifth image
    Case Else '70-99
        'Use sixth image
End Select
```

It's also worth noting that the `Random` class is inheritable so you can actually create your own class that allows you to specify weightings to the outcomes.  I have actually created a `WeightedRandom` class before but seem not to have kept it anywhere.  I think that I'll have to do that again and put it somewhere publicly accessible.

EDIT: Here's a more complete example:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private folderPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "imgsx")
    Private fileNames As String() = {"img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png", "img6.png"}
    Private imagesByFileName As New Dictionary(Of String, Image)
    Private rng As New Random

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Create one Image object per file.
        For Each fileName In fileNames
            Dim filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName)
            Dim img = Image.FromFile(filePath)

            imagesByFileName.Add(fileName, img)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Display a random image in each PictureBox on the form.
        For Each pictureBox In Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)
            pictureBox.Image = GetWeightedRandomImage()
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        'Clean up the Images to release the files.
        For Each fileName In fileNames
            imagesByFileName(fileName).Dispose()
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function GetWeightedRandomImage() As Image
        Dim fileNameIndex As Integer

        Select Case rng.Next(0, 100)
            Case Is < 10 '0-9
                fileNameIndex = 0
            Case Is < 30 '10-29
                fileNameIndex = 1
            Case Is < 40 '30-39
                fileNameIndex = 2
            Case Is < 60 '40-59
                fileNameIndex = 3
            Case Is < 70 '60-69
                fileNameIndex = 4
            Case Else '70-99
                fileNameIndex = 5
        End Select

        Return imagesByFileName(fileNames(fileNameIndex))
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: That's perfect, man. And is there any way to do that with 50 pictureboxes at a time, but without creating a pattern? Because for example, I could use your code and put that in the photo that has 10% chance, 5 pictureboxes would contain it. But the 5 would have the same picture and that's exactly what I do not want because although the photos change every time I use select case, in these 5 pictureboxes the photo would always be the same. It would be a standard, and I do not want it ;(

Comment: As is always the case when you want to do the same thing often, you put the common code in a method and then call that method each time you need that functionality.  You could, for instance, write a method that used the code above to decide which image to use and then returned that in an `Image` object.  The thing is though, you don't want to create multiple `Image` objects from the same file over and over.  You only need one `Image` object per file.  I'll create a fuller example but, before I do, please confirm something:

Comment: You have 50 `PictureBoxes` and 6 image files and you want only those 6 images to appear in all the `PictureBoxes`, but the number of times that each appears should be roughly based on your specific weightings, right?

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you very much, I'm happy just because you understood this, I could not explain.

Comment: Answer updated.  Note the superior method for getting the folder path you want.